# EF codefirst delete all child objects in a many-many scenario?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

How do I delete all child objects in in a many to many scenario? For example, I'd like to delete all `roles` belonging to a `user`.

I'm using EF code first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you must select all the roles 
and remove then from the user instance roles collection. Save

```
var usersRoles = user.Roles.ToList();

usersRoles.ForEach(role => user.Roles.Remove(role));

context.SaveChanges();

// Add new roles to the user
```

PS. the code may not be exact, but this is the logic that you should use to acomplish this.

Comment: The link table is the table that was generated? If it is, how would I cascade delete without deleting the user record?

Comment: from what I understand you wish to delete a user and its role association ?

Comment: no, just all the role associations. When I'm setting a role on the user, I remove all previous roles and add the new ones.

Answer (score 7):

Do you really want to delete roles belonging to user? It means that roles records will be deleted which will most probably result in exception because in many-to-many scenario roles will be usde by other users.

If you setup everything correctly this should simply remove relations between user and his roles:

```
var user = context.Users.Include("Roles").Single(u => u.Id == id);
user.Roles.Clear();
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

For many to many relationships the default in EF Code First is cascade delete if you're letting EF create the database.  So if you delete the User the roles should go away automatically.  If you have an existing database and can set it up for cascade delete that would probably still be the simplest and most efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to convert the set of entities to delete into a list so you can iterate and affect them.

```
var usersRoles = user.Roles.ToList();

foreach (var role in usersRoles )
   Context.DeleteObject(role );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the SaveChanges of my DbContext

```
var trackPublication = ChangeTracker.Entries<Publication>();
var dbEntityEntriesPublication = trackPublication as IList<DbEntityEntry<Publication>> ?? trackPublication.ToList();
foreach (var item in dbEntityEntriesPublication.Where(t => t.State == EntityState.Deleted))
        {
            item.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            item.Collection(m=>m.Groups).Load();
            item.Entity.Groups.Clear();
            item.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
```